# Is there a way to avoid submission with the same form values using react-hook-form, even though isDirty =true?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to validate that the form's values actually change before doing a submission, I'm using the form to perform a search also I'm using react-hook-form.
For example these are my fields: { name: 'sample1, mail: 'sample@test.com' }
I want to prevent a sumbmission if the user removes the 1 from the name and then adds it again because the results will be the same

My unique solution at the moment is to store the last values in a state (useState) and inside the submit handler compare each value to determine if something has changed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [useWatch](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usewatch/) or [watch](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch) to get form values and disable submit button if your values equal the initial values.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was resetting the form after each submission using the defualt values so now I reset the values by providing the last sumbission values so any change to any field will make dirty = true